# I've lost ability to hear stereo in my AirPods

Tags: audio, bluetooth, sound-volume, airpods

I've lost ability to hear stereo in my AirPods on one of my MacBooks. Built-in speakers still can play stereo, while AirPods cannot. Even Balance slider disappears when I switch to Air Pods.

[image]

How to fix?

I can hear stereo with the same Air Pods on other MacBook.

I tried forget device and reconnect it.

I am checking stereo with clips on Youtube.

Probably I've pressed something somewhere, but can't find.

---

Later after that I was seeing these headphones are determined as stereo on this notebook and then again as mono. Is there any way to control this?

---

I bought another BT headphones and they are also monophonic of this notebook, while being stereophonic on other comuters.

Comment: What do you mean by stereo? Sound?

Comment: Yes, sound in headphones is monophonic and balance is not adjustable

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked in System Settings>Accessibility>"Play stereo audio as mono"? It's possible that it was accidentally toggled or the system just went a little wonky.[image: System Settings>Accessibility>Stereo vs Mono Toggle]

Comment: Thank you will check next time I encounter this problem

Comment: No this is not the case